# I have a list written in a string how I can turn it into a real list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list written in a string
how I can turn it into a real list in Python
example:

```
list 1 = "[[1,2],
           [3,4]]"
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `ast.literal_eval` to **safely evaluate the list**

```
list_1 = "[[1,2], [3,4]]"
l=ast.literal_eval(list_1)
```

References:

- [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: I liked the random *"thank you"* :P

Comment: @schwobaseggl, windows 11, the fool put it in there somehow :)

Comment: Copied one line to many from the post :)